# How to bind bind inner json list to html row jqMobile table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, html-table

just I want to know how can I bind inner json list "pslList" to html row

```
    <table data-role="table" id="productOrders"  data-mode="reflow">
<thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Code</th>
                                  <th>Name</th>
                                  <th>Price</th>
                                  <th>Qty.</th>
                                  <th>Ext</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th>1</th>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                              <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
json
    [
        {
            "amount": 12,
            "podate": "2013-11-28T00:00:00",
            "ponumber": 7,
            "pslList": [
                {
                    "ext": 210,
                    "ponumber": 7,
                    "prodcd": "ffrff",
                    "price": 70,
                    "prodname": "games",
                    "qty": 3
                },
                {
                    "ext": 70,
                    "ponumber": 7,
                    "prodcd": "rrfrr",
                    "price": 14,
                    "prodname": "DVDs",
                    "qty": 5
                }
            ],
            "vendorno": 1
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After retrieving the json, you can iterate over the list, create rows and then add them to the table:

```
var $table = $('#productOrders tbody');
var plist = json[0].pslList;
for (i in plist) {
    var row = $('<tr><td>' + plist[i].prodcd + '</td><td>' + plist[i].prodname + '</td><td>' + plist[i].price + '</td><td>' + plist[i].qty + '</td><td>' + plist[i].ext + '</td></tr>');       
    $table.append(row);
}
```